# Get all products from multiple categories (Woocommerce/Wordpress)

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce, args

I want to display all products from multiple categories at once.

When i want to display all products from one category my $args array looks like this:

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'product',
   'product_cat' => 'backpacks',
   'orderby' => '_sku'
);
```

I remember that I can simply make an array inside my $args:

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'product',
   'product_cat' => array(
      'backpacks','accessoires',
),
   'orderby' => '_sku'
);
```

But it gives me the following error:

> Warning: urlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\live\wp-includes\formatting.php on line 4312

I know this is a simple thing but i cant figure out why its not working.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try below snippet.

```
$sortcolumn = 'ID';
$prod_categories = array(12, 17); //category IDs
$product_args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'private', 'draft'),
    'post_type' => array('product', 'product_variation'), //skip types
    'orderby' => $sortcolumn,
    'order' => 'ASC',
);

if (!empty($prod_categories)) {
    $product_args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $prod_categories,
            'operator' => 'IN',
    ));
}

$products = get_posts($product_args);
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a simple way to do it

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'backpacks'
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'accessoires'
    )
),
);
```